# Can't resolve '../package' and Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' when import sqlite3 in Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

When I run 'NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config webpack.react.config.js --mode development' npm scripts, there are some errors happened:

1. Error: Can't resolve '../package' in 'xxx/node-gyp/lib'
2. Error: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk' in 'xxx/node-pre-gyp/lib'

The package of version:

1. Electron: 11.0.2
2. node: v12.18.3
3. node-gyp: 3.8.0
4. sqlite3 5.0.0

The code of import sqlite3:

```js
import * as sqlite from 'sqlite3'
```

I have already rebuild sqlite3 module. And I think it maybe caused by node-gyp version or webpack configuration. But I try long time to solve it but not work.

If you want more code detail, please tell me. Thanks for your help!